# How to program projected capacitive touch screen?

Tags: touchscreen

This is my first time on this website. I tried to search for my question in archive but couldn't get what I needed. So, it would be great if someone could help me to answer this question.

QUESTION:

So, as we know that all the capacitive touch screen devices basically have following states :-

WAKE  --- backlight is on and touch coordinates are generated

SLEEP --- backlight is off and no touch coordinates are generated

So, my question is that, is it possible for us to design a new state in which I could have this configuration " backlight is off and touch coordinates are generated " . OR Is there any way to program the WAKE state such that the backlight can be turned off ( looks like screen is off ) but still touch coordinates could be generated.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This will vary depending on device and OS. Are you trying to do this on a specific device?